# speedy_c2dm: NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, android-c2dm

I set up speedy_c2dm to send "push" messages to android devices.

The gem was working fine, but now I get this NoMethodError message when I call

```
SpeedyC2DM::API.send_notification(options)
```

the options parameter is good, I have verified this.
From the [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/s/speedy_c2dm-1.0.1/SpeedyC2DM/API.html#method-c-send_notification) I got the following code from the gem:

```
def get_auth_token(email, password)
  data = "accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=#{email}&Passwd=#{password}&service=ac2dm"
  headers = { "Content-type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "Content-length" => "#{data.length}"}

  uri = URI.parse(AUTH_URL)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  response, body = http.post(uri.path, data, headers)
  return body.split("\n")[2].gsub("Auth=", "")
end
```

You can see that the last line uses gsub, so I believe the problem is in the authentication method.

I have changed the password of the account since I created this, I updated the file with the password, initializers/speedy_c2dm.rb:

```
C2DM_API_EMAIL = "myemail@gmail.com"
C2DM_API_PASSWORD = "mynewpassword"

SpeedyC2DM::API.set_account(C2DM_API_EMAIL, C2DM_API_PASSWORD)
```

Can this be causing the error? That I changed the password even though I updated this file?
(Google doesn't let me to go back to the old password, I have to create a new one different from the old ones if I change it again)
Its the only thing I can think of since I didn't modify the gem's code.
How can I fix it? [C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) is deprecated now, but its supposed to keep working for old users. I don't want to migrate to [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) if I don't need to, everything is set up to work with C2DM

Any other ideas to fix it are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed after I removed the "[two step verification](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744)" for logging in to my email.

This change can be made in the account configuration of gmail.